# Find the total space occupied by the ISO's on FS?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, du

I want a awk script to find the sum `$1` of the output of

`sudo find / -type f -iname *.iso -print0 | xargs -0 du`

Though it wouldn't be difficult to bring the output in human readable format but  it would be good if it can be done on the fly.

The output looks like this:

```
ejs@sanctum:/tmp$ sudo find / -type f -iname *.iso -print0 | xargs -0 du
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
2696508 /media/ejs/huge390GB/firefox_downloads/BSD release/FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso
1434624 /media/ejs/huge390GB/home_old/mymac/Downloads/Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso
2099200 /media/ejs/huge390GB/home_old/mymac/Downloads/Fedora-Server-DVD-x86_64-23.iso
2891700 /media/ejs/huge390GB/isos/gentooLinux.iso
270336  /media/ejs/huge390GB/isos/gparted-live-0.25.0-1-i686.iso
3198720 /media/ejs/huge390GB/isos/windows 10/Windows.iso
6208608 /media/ejs/huge390GB/isos/Windows 10 Final AIO (22 in 1) (32 Bit and 64 Bit) ISO + activator/Windows_10_AIO_22in1_x86_x64.iso
3198720 /media/ejs/huge390GB/isos/Windows.iso
1010688 /media/ejs/huge390GB/hadoop/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
700928  /media/ejs/huge390GB/ubuntu_souvenior/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/archlinux-2016.01.01-dual.iso
13680   /media/ejs/huge390GB/ubuntu_souvenior/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/kali-linux-2016.1-amd64/kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso
102400  /media/ejs/huge390GB/windowsbackup/SystemReserved_sda1.iso
122776576   /media/ejs/huge390GB/windowsbackup/Windows_sda2.iso
699520  /media/ejs/huge390GB/otherHDD/desk-things/archlinux-2016.01.01-dual.iso
6976    /media/ejs/huge390GB/otherHDD/sweeping/datamining/desk/mydesk/vai.iso
627872  /media/ejs/huge390GB/otherHDD/sweeping/prev_downloads/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso
4963328 /media/ejs/huge390GB/otherHDD/sweeping/prev_downloads/Qubes-R3.1-rc2-x86_64.iso
300164  /media/ejs/myspace226/boxes/page5/play_xxe.iso
3092932 /media/ejs/myspace226/oldWinDesktop/new desktop/desk/windows 10/Windows.iso
5986044 /media/ejs/myspace226/WinDownload11.10.16/prev/Windows 10 Final AIO (22 in 1) (32 Bit and 64 Bit) ISO + activator/Windows_10_AIO_22in1_x86_x64.iso
1796    /media/ejs/41791947-27ae-4b0f-9dd4-2d3a2f442dea/usr/lib/memtest86+/memtest86+.iso
3004772 /media/ejs/41791947-27ae-4b0f-9dd4-2d3a2f442dea/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso
102400  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-2418281319-387379063-377695367-1000/$R4KMAWS/SystemReserved_sda1.iso
70466560    /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/backup/kali_backup.iso
102400  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/backup/windowsbackup/SystemReserved_sda1.iso
122776576   /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/backup/windowsbackup/Windows_sda2.iso
237280  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/21LTR.com_Scene1_2.120_v1.0.iso
221184  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/axis2_and_tomcat_manager.iso
11512   /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/BadStore_123s.iso
191488  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2007-1860.iso
177152  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2008-1930.iso
176128  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2012-1823.iso
339968  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2012-2661.iso
168960  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2012-6081.iso
19584   /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/cve-2014-6271.iso
1752028 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/DVL_1.5_Infectious_Disease.iso
491244  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/DVWA-1.0.7.iso
177152  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/ecb.iso
176128  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/from_sqli_to_shell.iso
177152  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/from_sqli_to_shell_II.iso
167936  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/from_sqli_to_shell_pg_edition.iso
416768  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/GameOver.0.1.null.iso
191488  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/linux_host_review.iso
446416  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/Loophole.iso
320512  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/rack_cookies_and_commands_injection.iso
179200  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/php_include_and_post_exploitation.iso
100480  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/play_session_injection.iso
179200  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/web_for_pentester.iso
361472  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/web_for_pentester_II.iso
193536  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/boxes/xss_and_mysql_file.iso
301376  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/boxes/page5/play_xxe.iso
1887432 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/data/iv videos/iv_videos.iso
6329536 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/GAMES/Bioshock Series/BIOSHOCK/BIOSHOCK.ISO
5384120 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/GAMES/Outlast.Whistleblower-RELOADED/rld-outwhistle.iso
4159488 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/GAMES/POP/Disc/Prince of Persia - Warrior Within.iso
516224  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/programming/tejas_folder/imp softwares/VedaBase2003.iso
3344512 /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/programming/tejas_folder/os/Fedora 8 i386 DV.iso
993280  /media/ejs/BEAE4EDCAE4E8CB9/programming/tejas_folder/os/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
2099204 /media/ejs/home/mymac/Downloads/Fedora-Server-DVD-x86_64-23.iso
1434628 /media/ejs/home/mymac/Downloads/Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso
1451060 /media/ejs/home/mymac/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
751640  /media/ejs/home/mymac/Downloads/archlinux-2016.05.01-dual.iso
848856  /media/ejs/home/mymac/MultiCD/FreeBSD-11.0-CURRENT-amd64-20160518-r300097-disc1.iso
1008    /media/ejs/home/mymac/MultiCD/multicd.iso
751620  /media/ejs/home/mymac/MultiCD/archlinux-2016.05.01-dual.iso
1220    /media/ejs/windows/Program Files (x86)/NeoSmart Technologies/EasyBCD/profiles/nst_mac.iso
544 /media/ejs/windows/Program Files (x86)/NeoSmart Technologies/EasyBCD/profiles/plop.iso
16  /root/doc.iso
25092   /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/padding_oracle.iso
7872    /usr/share/u3-pwn/backup/origU3/U3 System.iso
4   /usr/share/doc/minicom/tables/mc.iso
57088   /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
504648  /home/ejs/Downloads/Project IGI.iso
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `awk` when `du` can do it for you?

```
sudo find / -type f -iname *.iso -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- --total
```

`du` can take a list of files from a file (or stdin if the file is `-`), and it can print the total:

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.iso' -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- --total
1006M   ./OS/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
1.4G    ./OS/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
1.5G    ./OS/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso
3.9G    total
```

Comment: that was smooth ... `--snip-- |awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum;}'` i tried this and brought the ouput to human readable format by manual calc... this was educational... thnx

Answer (score 0):

I always use 'du -sh *' to find the amount of space various directory trees use. You could put the ISOs into a folder and run that command, replacing * with the folder name. You could integrate this into your script.

Comment: thats the point i cannot put them in a one folder (which would be on a ext HDD) thats the reason i want to know this

Comment: `awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum;}' /tmp/size` this worked